# excel macro to reset/refresh a table column having dropdown

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, macros

A newbie to excel macro so kindly bear if my question looks stupid.
I have created a table (listobjects ) in worksheet having four columns. The fourth column is incorporated with drop downs through data validation and has values as "a, b, c,none". Now for the first time I open up the sheet, select the values from drop down and it works fine but for the second time, when I open the sheet the drop down values in the columns remains the same as previously entered.
Can any one help me with a macro code which I can assign to a button, clicking which would reset the drop down values to "none" (as default value) and allow me to select again from the choices mentioned in the drop down.

Any leads would be appreciated.
Pavan Patro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why you would want to do that.
But the following macro should work (because I just tested it out)

Assuming your table name is Table1, this will clear all content and make it empty:

```
Sub ClearChoice()
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").ListColumns(4).DataBodyRange.ClearContents
End Sub
```

Alternatively, you can set it to "none" if you wish:

```
Sub ClearChoice()
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").ListColumns(4).DataBodyRange.Value = "none"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Edmund, will check this out and let you know at the earliest.... Appreciate your help.:-)

Comment: Awesome, Works absolutely fine Edmund..... Thanks a ton :-)

Comment: Edmund if you could help me some more queries......

Comment: Sure! No problem! Glad to help